# Н в слове "слюнки" твёрдая?

Tags: фонетика, орфоэпия

В словарях вроде твёрдо предлагают говорить. Или можно и так, и так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно произносить и так, и так. Современная норма склоняется к твёрдому [н], но ещё не отжила своё старомосковская норма, где наблюдается ассимиляция согласных по мягкости-твёрдости и слово произносится как [с'л'Ун'к'ь].

Comment: Спасибо! Какая точная транскрипция, особенно последний звук!